# Merge multiple .bash_history files with timestamps

Tags: bash, command-history

I have generated multiple `.bash_history` files by switching between snapshots on a VM.  I would like to recover all these files into the single live `.bash_history` file in my currently running instance.

The files have timestamps in them and I would like to preserve them as much as possible.  However, it looks like some lines don't have timestamps on them.  For example:

```
#1542817796
vi ~/.bash_profile 
set +x
cd -
cd w/Edge-Agent/edge-agent-ged/
make 
set -x
man make
make -npq
make -npq .DEFAULT
make 
make 
ack npq /etc
ack npq /usr/share/
set +x
ack npq /usr/share/
sudo vi /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/make
dv
hg diff 
vi ~/.bashrc
#1542826064
ls
#1542826066
vi ~/.bashrc
#1542826074
cd ..
#1542826321
```

I would like to order the merged list by timestamp because I was switching back and forth between the snapshots and the files interleave with each other.  If there's no timestamp available for a command we can infer it from the last timestamp before and the first timestamp after.

Comment: What are the existing bash_history filenames to merge?

Comment: edgeos_history.[012]

Comment: How to read that sample? Any command without a time stamp needs the previous time stamp assigned?

Comment: @RudiC sure. That works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using GNU m4 (which supports [numbered diversions up to LONG_MAX](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/m4/manual/m4-1.4.18/html_node/Divert.html)) with some additional `sed` to prepare the input:

```
#!/bin/sh

{ cat <<"EOF"
m4_define(m4_chunk,`m4_divert(-1)m4_undivert($1)m4_divert($1)#$1')m4_dnl
m4_define(m4_,``m4_'')m4_dnl
m4_define(`m4_LQ',`m4_changequote([,])`m4_dnl'
m4_changequote`'')m4_dnl
m4_define(`m4_RQ',`m4_changequote([,])m4_dnl`
'm4_changequote`'')m4_dnl
EOF
sed -e "s/m4_/m4_()/g;s/\`/m4_LQ()/g;s/'/m4_RQ()/g;s/m4_/\`'m4_/g" -e 's/^#\([0-9]\+\)$/m4_chunk(\1)/'
} | m4 -P
```

Usage:

```
cat edgeos_history.* | sort_history.sh > merged_history
```

The `m4_chunk` function does most of the work, as the separate blocks are "undiverted" in ascending numerical order when all the input ends.  The rest of the script is to protect any quotemarks and existing `m4_` sequences in the input from being interpreted by `m4`.

`LQ` and `RQ` definitions based on those in Michael Breen's [Notes on the M4 Macro Language](https://mbreen.com/m4.html#quotemacro).

Comment: Does it have to be left-justified?  Just curious.

Comment: The lines inside the here-doc do, because `m4` passes whitespace through unchanged.

Comment: Some of the lines are in more than one file so I'm getting duplicate lines like this:
`#1542121355
scripts/run-system-tests-local.sh -d srasku0 -s TC263808 | ts %T
#1542121355
scripts/run-system-tests-local.sh -d srasku0 -s TC263808 | ts %T
`.  Is there a way to resolve this?  If not, I could write a simple Perl script to post-process the file.

Comment: You could prepend `m4_divert(-1)m4_undivert($1)` to the definition of `m4_chunk`, so that any duplicate timestamp discards any lines previously seen with that same timestamp.

Comment: Cool.  That works.

Comment: Edited.  However, you may still be better off with a script written in a more flexible language.

Comment: Yeah, I would probably accept a solution written in Perl over this one but I don't have one.

Comment: There are ways of doing Here docs with Indent!
See https://antofthy.gitlab.io/info/shell/file.txt   and search for "HERE, Here, here"

Answer (score 0):

Why not just do something like `cat /path/to/one/.bash_history >> /path/to/live/.bash_history` then you could remove duplicate enteries with `awk '!seen[$0]++' .bash_history >> .bash_history2` then remove the original and rename .bash_history2 to .bash_history. However removing the duplicates like that will leave empty timestamps.

Comment: I would like to sort by time stamp. I’ll make that clearer on my question.

Comment: Yea that makes it more complicated

Answer (score 0):

Would this help:

```
awk '/^#[0-9]*$/ {TS = $0; next} {print TS, $0}' file* | sort
#1542817796 ack npq /etc
#1542817796 ack npq /usr/share/
#1542817796 ack npq /usr/share/
#1542817796 cd -
#1542817796 cd w/Edge-Agent/edge-agent-ged/
#1542817796 dv
#1542817796 hg diff 
#1542817796 make 
#1542817796 make 
#1542817796 make 
#1542817796 make -npq
.
.
.
```

Make sure to list ALL history files as input stream to `awk`.

**EDIT:** Some non-satisfying, non-portable essays to retain the original order of the commands:

```
awk '/^#[0-9]*$/ {TS = $0; next} {print TS, NR, $0}' file* | sort  -k1,1 -k2,2n
```

.

```
awk '/^#[0-9]*$/ {TS = $0; next} {print TS,  $0}' file* | sort  -mk1,1
```

Comment: Since this uses the same timestamp for all consecutive untimestamped entries it will sort those entries lexically instead of by the original order in the file.  I think this can be improved by incrementing the inferred timestamp somehow.

Comment: I edited two more options in, none of which is necessarily satisfying nor portable.

Answer (score 0):

For a long time I looked for a way to merge bash history (with timestamps), and nothing seemed acceptable.

That is... Merge the on-disk ".bash_history" with the in-memory shell 'history'. Preserving timestamp ordering, and command order within those timestamps.

Optionally removing unique commands (even if multi-line), and/or removing (cleaning out) simple and/or sensitive commands, according to defined perl RE's.   Adjust to suit!

This is the result:
https://antofthy.gitlab.io/software/history_merge.bash.txt

The first 'perl' command in the script just concatenates the input history files.. defaulting to `"$HISTFILE" <(history -w /dev/stdout)` to merge on-disk history with in-memory history, seperating them into time stamped records.  The second 'perl' then does the merge.

It saves the result in a temporary file which can optionally replace on-disk history, or in-momory history as you like (current does both).

Adjust to suit.

Enjoy

Comment: Can you explain exactly how the OP can use your script to do what the question is asking for?